# Should I always deal with reference returning vector?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, stl

Not sure [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96619fe6334bf6d0) what's happening:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Voice
{
public:
    double mValue = 0.0;

    Voice() { }
    Voice(const Voice &copy) {
    }    
};

class VoiceManager
{
public:
    std::vector<Voice> mVoices;

    VoiceManager() {
        mVoices = std::vector<Voice>(numVoices, Voice());   

        for (int i = 0; i < numVoices; i++) {
            mVoices[i].mValue = 100.0;
        }        
    }

private:
    int numVoices = 16;    
};

int main()
{    
    VoiceManager voiceManager;
    Voice voice = voiceManager.mVoices[2];
    std::cout << voice.mValue << std::endl;
}
```

I set `mValue` for each `Voice` with value `100` with operator `[]`, but when I try to retrieve the object with the same `[]` operator, it seems it returns not that element? It prints 0.

Instead, if I do:

```
Voice &voice = voiceManager.mVoices[2];
```

I can finally see the updated value.

What's happening here?

Comment: What does `Voice::Voice(Voice const&)` do?

Comment: Your copy-constructor does the wrong thing; I suspect that fixing it will fix your problem. You could omit it and fall back to the implicitly-generated one; or do `mValue = copy.mValue;`

Comment: Your copy constructor doesn't actually make a copy.  Just get rid of it and use the compiler provided one that will.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments, your copy constructor is a) wrong and b) superfluous

```
class Voice
{
public:
    double mValue = 0.0;

    // don't provide default constructor, unless you have another constructor
    // use compiler-generated copy-constructor
};

class VoiceManager
{
    int numVoices = 16;    // move up here so that member-initialization works
public:
    std::vector<Voice> mVoices;

    VoiceManager() 
    :
        mVoices(numVoices) // member-initialize
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numVoices; i++) {
            mVoices[i].mValue = 100.0;
        }        
    }
};

int main()
{    
    VoiceManager voiceManager;
    Voice voice = voiceManager.mVoices[2];
    std::cout << voice.mValue << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wRuqHrPU37eIqLmW)

Note that I also did a minor cleanup on the constructor for `VoiceManager`, by using member-initialization syntax.

As for the other question: the initialization

```
Voice voice = voicemanager.mVoice[2];
```

actually calls your copy constructor

```
Voice(voicemanager.mVoice[2]);
```

(the `=` sign here does not imply assignment!)

Comment: But I ask why :) Why if I use `mVoices[i].mValue = 100.0;` it sets the value to the "copy", while `Voice voice = voiceManager.mVoices[2];` doesn't return the "copy" instance?

Comment: @paizza your copy constructor was empty

Comment: I see :) But I don't set there the mValue. I set here `mVoices[i].mValue = 100.0;`. So whereever I set that value, when I return the same voice (i.e. `Voice voice = voiceManager.mVoices[2];`) I should see the set value. No?

Comment: @paizza `Voice voice = voiceManager.mVoices[2];` actually calls `Voice(voiceManager.mVoices[2])`, i.e the copy constructor, and that was empty. Note that copy-initialization (using the `=`) is not the same as assignment!

Comment: "the = sign here does not imply assignment!)" ??? Really? It doesn't return Voice stored in the vector at position 2? :O

Comment: @paizza yes, really. There is a difference between `Voice v; v = voicemanager.mVoices[2];` (default construction + assigment) and `Voice v = voicemanager.mVoices[2];` (copy-initialization). That's why the rule-of-3 existed: if you override any of the copy constructor, copy assignment or destructor, override them all and make them consistent